# Mapping amount of properties

Tags: mapping, owl

i want to map 2 different Ontologies A and B. But the classes i want to map have a different amount of object properties.Lets say A equals b. A is father and B is mother. class A:(gender, age, eyecolour, brother) class B:(age, gender, haircolour, sport)
the Union of A and B say C got:(gender, age, eyecolour, haircolour, sport) right? Is there any create statement in owL? or do i need to make the equvivalent to statement for the object properties. Is there any statement lets say if A got 2 brothers, create the object property x in B.

Answer (score 0):

OWL classes aren't classes in the object-oriented programming sense, properties don't "belong" to classes in the sense that methods belong to classes (in many OO programming languages).  When you say that the domain of a property P is the class C, it means that whenever you have an assertion

P(x,y)

you can infer that

x is a C

If you assert that the

```
P domain A  
Q domain A

R domain B
S domain B
T domain B
```

and then assert that

```
C equivalentClass (A union B)
```

then you'll be able to infer that

```
P domain C
Q domain C
R domain C
S domain C
T domain C
```

Since, e.g.,

```
P(x,y)
```

implies

```
x is an A
```

which in turn implies that

```
x is a (A union B)
```

which implies that

```
x is a C
```

So C is a domain of P.  I think that's what you're meaning when you say that "the class C has property P."